# Getting too much TCP-ESTABLISHED connection while using kafka producer in java application. why? Can anybody tell about this?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am using apache kafka-client-3.2.0 (also used latest Apache kafka-client-3.4.0 jar) for creating producer in java. I have 5 topics with replication-factor=1 and partitions=1 for each topic as I have only 1 broker. Out of these 5 topics 1 is being used by KafkaAppender from log4j2 and 4 are being used by a timer task which periodically calls the producer to dump on these topics. When I starts the application the number of tcp connection starts increasing. It has been found that more than 300 connections are established and are also increasing.

kafka-version kafka-2.13_2.8.0, kafka-2.13_3.3.1 and kafka-2.13_3.4.0

Below is the producer configuration I am using:

```
    private KafkaProducer<String, String> producer;
        public KafkaProducer<String, String> getProducer() {
                return producer;
            }
        private KafkaProducer<String, String> 
        createAndGetProducer(String acksConfig, int retryConfig){
                Properties props = new Properties();
             
       props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers);
                props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, acksConfig);
                props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, retryConfig);
             
       props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
    "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
             
       props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
    "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
                KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new 
        KafkaProducer<>(props);
            
            return producer;
        }
```

Below is the method which I am calling from timer task to produce data:

```
    public static void writeToTopic(String topicName, String value){
            logger.info("Writing into topic " + topicName);
            
            ProducerRecord <String, String> producerData = new ProducerRecord <String, String> (topicName, value);
            KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = KafkaConnectionManager.getConnection().getProducer();
            
            logger.info(producer.toString());
            KafkaConnectionManager.getConnection().getProducer().send(producerData);
            KafkaConnectionManager.getConnection().getProducer().flush();
        }
```

Below are the connections:

```
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:59604      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:48358      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:50668      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:59898      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:50626      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:59444      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:49716      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:61049      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:58516      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:51514      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:51892      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:50802      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:47106      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:60084      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:50588      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:50682      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:59814      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:50788      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:48554      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:51390      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:58576      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:50974      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:51504      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:47262      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:60022      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:50558      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:56118      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:51844      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:59712      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:51834      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:50626      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
tcp6       0      0  X.X.X.X:9092       X.X.X.X:59668      ESTABLISHED 4369/java
```

---

Below is the Connection Manager Code

```
    private static KafkaConnectionManager kafkaConnectionManager = null;
    
    public synchronized static KafkaConnectionManager getConnection() {     
            return kafkaConnectionManager;
        }
    
    public synchronized static KafkaConnectionManager initialize(Properties kafkaProps, Logger logger, String hostIp) throws KafkaConnectionManagerException {      
            if (kafkaConnectionManager == null) {
                synchronized (KafkaConnectionManager.class) {
                    if (kafkaConnectionManager == null) {
                        kafkaConnectionManager = new KafkaConnectionManager(kafkaProps, logger, hostIp);
                    }
                }
            }
            return kafkaConnectionManager;
        }
    
    private KafkaConnectionManager(Properties kafkaProps, Logger logger, String hostIp) throws KafkaConnectionManagerException{
            if(kafkaProps == null)
            {
                throw new KafkaConnectionManagerException("kafkaProps property is null");
            }
            else if(logger == null)
            {
                throw new KafkaConnectionManagerException("logger is null");
            }
            else if(hostIp == null)
            {
                throw new KafkaConnectionManagerException("hostIp is null, set the hostIp");
            }
            KafkaConnectionManager.kafkaProps = kafkaProps;
            this.logger = logger;
            this.hostIp = hostIp;
            brokers = kafkaProps.getProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG).trim();
            logger.info("KAFKA brokers!!! = "+brokers);
            this.acksConfig = kafkaProps.getProperty(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG).trim();
            this.retryConfig = Integer.parseInt(kafkaProps.getProperty(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG).trim());
            
            this.producer = createAndGetProducer(acksConfig, retryConfig);
    logger.info("Kafka Producer has been Initialized successfully");
            
        }
```

---

In the above code snippet method "public synchronized static KafkaConnectionManager initialize" is called from main method.

---

Below is the broker configuration I am using (same for all version mentioned above)

```
broker.id=1
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://X.X.X.X:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
num.network.threads=3 
num.io.threads=8 
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400 
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600

log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1


offsets.topic.replication.factor=1 transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

log.flush.interval.messages=10000 
log.flush.interval.ms=1000

log.retention.hours=168 
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

zookeeper.connect=10.64.223.70:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000

group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0 
max.connection.per.ip=100 
max.connections=100
listener.name.internal.max.connections=100
request.timeout.ms=180000
connections.max.idle.ms=300000
```

---

I am also using AdminAPI for creating topic. It is called also from main method. Below is the code for Topic Creation using Admin API

```
 public void createTopics(Collection<NewTopic> newTopics, CreateTopicsOptions createTopicsOptions) {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers);
        AdminClient adminClient = KafkaAdminClient.create(props);

        adminClient.createTopics(newTopics, createTopicsOptions);
    }
```

---

I tried all the configuration mentioned in kafka's official website for broker config and producer config expect for authentication I am not using any authentication now.

Comment: If you have already initialised the Kafka Producer in 1st image, why are you getting the instance from ConnectionManager? Also which documentation you followed to write this code? Adding more resources to the questions helps us to answer better

Comment: Please share the KafkaConnectionManager.getConnection() code

Comment: Please edit your code to include code as text, not images

Comment: `KafkaProducer` is thread-safe. You do not need a "Connection Manager". I suspect this is where your error is...

Comment: @Neenad This code was actually written by one of my colleague around 1 and half years ago. So, I don't know what document he followed. I am currently following kafka's official documentation.
Here connection manager is a singleton class which has a getter for producer object. I've added code snippet for connection manager also.

Comment: @ahmed.ettoumi I've added code snippet for connection manager also.

Comment: @OneCricketeer This code was actually written by one of my colleague around 1 and half years ago. I don't know why did he wrote a connection manager. I've added code for connection manager also.

Comment: Could you also post the complete code for timer task, I feel somwhere you are reinitialising the entire connection manager multiple times without closing the previous one

Comment: Unrelated, but have you never restarted Kafka in a whole year + half for any maintenance? You should not be storing Kafka data under /tmp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singletons are an anti-pattern, and doesn't improve anything here.

You can construct one `KafkaProducer` in the lifecycle of your application, and then simply re-use that (assuming no configs of it need to change).

Same applies for the `AdminClient`; create one, then pass it around as a parameter to methods / classes that need it, not construct a new one every method call.